# Percentile Rank and Percentile

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, percentile

I was watching the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Snf6Wpn-L4c). For an $n$ object numeric list, consider $x_{i}$ to be the $n$th value along its index.

> $\text{Percentile Rank of $x_i$}=\frac{\text{Number of Values Below }  x_i}{n}\cdot 100$.

The number of values below $x_i$ is $i-1$. So, $\text{Percentile Rank of $x_i$}=\frac{i-1}{n}\cdot 100\implies \frac{\text{Percentile Rank of $x_i$}}{100}\cdot n+1=i$.

Why does this value say $i=\frac{percentile}{100}(n+1)$ in the video? Wouldn't it make sense to add one like the equation above instead of the $\frac{percentile}{100}$? I feel like I am missing something subtle.

Comment: Whatever the explanation for the discrepancy, I would note that there is not much difference. Between the two formulas for $i$, the difference is $1-\frac{\text{percentile}}{100}$ which is between $0$ and $1$. For example, if $n$ is 1000, one of these formulas might give you $i=601$ and the other gives $i=600.6$. For most practical purposes, it's not a big deal if you fudge the 601st entry with the 600th entry.

Comment: A percentile is such an elementary concept in mathematics. You are literally taking a percentage of a finite list of elements. There is no reason to be off by one. There has got to be a reason why those equations above do not match! As a teacher, I do not know which one to tell my students to use which is embarrassing to me.

Comment: With quartiles, you do your best to divide the data set into 4 equal-sized bins (as evenly as possible). Even then, there are at least three different conventions for how this is actually accomplished. With percentiles, when you are trying to subdivide into 100 equal-sized bins as evenly as possible. There is more than one convention for doing this. That resource you cite _should_ be internally consistent, but in general it might be good to expose students to how more than one convention exists and they can differ (but only slightly).

Comment: I get there are varying definitions out there for this. I don't get why these equations are different! I mean evidently, they are not equal. What is the reason for this? I get the concept of quartiles and percentiles as anyone would. I don't get why these definitions are messed up. I mean why are they different here?

Comment: Was it that the median needed to be assigned a certain value for this situation? Was it that the first quartile needed to be partitioned evenly and prevent this from happening for the first definition and not the second? That is what I am asking... Does that make sense?

Comment: It could be simply a mistake/inconsistency on the part of the person who made the video.

Comment: Do you think the first definition is correct then? Which is more common?

Comment: I don't feel qualified to say which, if either, is more common. It seems that the important thing is to partition $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into 100 parts in some reasonable way, and both of these feel reasonable. But consider if you want the "0th percentile" to make sense. With the first formula, "0th percentile" happens for $i=1$. With the second formula, a "0th percentile" would imply $i=0$, so it's not possible.